# methods interfere with finding the "Min" and "Max" numbers of array

Tags: java, arrays, max, min

This is a perceptual question.
I want to know why there is an interference with these two independent methods.
I know both are reading the same array (`my_array`)
independently every response of the methods is correct. But when I turn on both of them (min and max methods), the response of the below method is wrong.

This is my code:

```
public class myPractice {
    public static int max(int[] my_array1) {
        int i = 0;
        int max = my_array1[i];
         for(i = 0; i < my_array1.length-1; i++) {
             if(my_array1[i] > my_array1[i+1]) {
                 my_array1[i+1] = my_array1[i];
                 max = my_array1[i];
             }else {
                 max = my_array1[i+1];
             }
         } 
         System.out.println("Max= " +max); 
         return max;
    }
    
    public static int min(int[] my_array2) {
        int j = 0;
         int min = my_array2[j];
         for(j = 0; j < my_array2.length-1; j++) {
             if(my_array2[j] < my_array2[j+1]) {
                 my_array2[j+1] = my_array2[j];
                 min = my_array2[j];
             }else {
                 min = my_array2[j+1];
             }
         } 
         System.out.println("Min= " +min);
         return min;
    }
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         
         int[] my_array = {25, 14, 56, 5, 36, 89, 77, 18, 29, 49};
         
         max(my_array);
         min(my_array);

    }
    
}
```

Comment: What are 'good' responses and what are 'wrong' responses? Please put all that information into your post. Also, I assume this is Java? If so, please tag the language to increase visibility.

Comment: If you perceive that `max()` doesn't modify the contents of the array, you are incorrect. (Did you mean to swap values instead of just overwriting lowers with the highest so far?) "It's the same array" with not even the same numbers in a different order.

Comment: What are the methods `min(int[])` and `max(int[])` supposed to be doing?  I assume from the names that these find the min and max value respectively - but that doesn't appear to be what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are altering the input array in the `min` and `max` methods:

```java
my_array1[i+1] = my_array1[i];
```

As a result, in the next call, you are manipulating an array different from the initial one. As a matter of fact, in your script, `max(my_array)` sets `my_array` equals to [25, 25, 56, 56, 56, 89, 89, 89, 89, 89].

You can simplify `min` and `max` as the following ones:

```java
public static int max(int[] myArr) {
    int max = myArr[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < myArr.length; i++){
        if (myArr[i] > max)
            max = myArr[i];
    }

   return max;
}

public static int min(int[] myArr) {
    int min = myArr[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < myArr.length; i++){
        if (myArr[i] < min)
            min = myArr[i];
    }

    return min;
}
```

Furthermore, I want to recommend some best practices:

- use the camel case when programming in java. Write `myArray` instead of `my_array`;
- print the result of a method in the main:

  ```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      int[] myArray = {25, 14, 56, 5, 36, 89, 77, 18, 29, 49};

      System.out.println("Max = " + max(myArray));
      System.out.println("Min = " + min(myArray));

  }
  ```